# how can you create multiple on focus and onblur?

Tags: javascript, forms, onblur, onfocus

I want to know how to create multiple `onfocus` and `onblur` for multiple input fields.

I have something like this but when the name field is `onfocus`, the email field is `onfocus` too. Is there a way to solve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     focusBlur();
});


function focusBlur() {

    var formName = document.getElementById('name');
    var valueName = 'name';

    var formEmail = document.getElementById('email');
    var valueEmail = 'email';

    formName.onfocus = function() {
        if(formName.value == valueName) {
            formName.value = '';
        } 

        if(formEmail.value == valueEmail) {
            formEmail.value = '';
        }
    };


    formName.onblur = function() {
        if(formName.value == '') {
            formName.value = valueName;
        }

        if(formEmail.value == '') {
            formEmail.value = valueEmail;
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: if you're already using jQuery, why not use it all the way?

Comment: you can attach a class to all of them and just go `$(your form).on('mouseover', '.anyclass', function() { // do something } `

Comment: i want to practice javascript..

Comment: jQuery has its own way of wrapping event listeners which isn't interoperable with vanilla. Don't mix.

Comment: i didn't use vanilla.

Comment: "vanilla" = no library. Anyway, not sure I understand what you're trying to do and how it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure two UI elements cannot have focus simultaneously, though a single focus event could conceivably propagate past them both.

Comment: can someone help me with javascript?

Comment: I'm trying to onfocus and onblur the name value when I click on the name value. Also same for the email value. but right now they are onfocus n onblur at the same time, and that is not what i want. So I want to write clean javascript . and how to put multipe onfocus n onblur together

Comment: You're not making things clearer yet. Clicking on an input that isn't disabled will, by default, focus it. You can't "onfocus" or "unblur" things (those are event handlers). What you can do is `focus()` or `blur()` them. And you can only ever focus one element at a time (the previously focused element will lose focus as soon as you focus another).

Answer (score 0):

If you where to do something like JQuery does you could say something like

```
function blur(){}
  var elems=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))
elems.forEach(function(element){

  if(document.addEventListener){
        element.addEventListener('blur',blur)
  }
  else if(element.onblur){
        element.onblur=blur;
  }
})
```

something like that should do it. depending on the browser support you can use getElementsByClassName or querySelector that will return an array of nodes and the loop through it to attach the events

Comment: This is wrong on several levels. The old 'on*' properties are pretty much supported everywhere, they're just not as flexible as the modern addEventListener version. `getElementsByTagName` and other DOM methods will return an HTMLCollection which unfortunately doesn't implement Array methods like forEach.

Comment: you are right, i had it wrong on the attachment methods, as for the collection it was an oversight  a simple array conversion would solve the problem. Thanks for the pointers